# guide me to find the best android programming pdf

Tags: android

What the best android programming education pdf to learn fast and easily  android programming?please guide me,thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Best" is very subjective, so it is hard to accurately answer your question.

However, the official Android documentation is probably a good place to start; check out the [Hello, World](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) app (it's a website, rather than a pdf though...).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to see this videos :

http://www.youtube.com/user/edu4java#grid/user/301ACBB31D739F72

They has it in spanish also , and have another list for android game program.

P.D: No pdf , but faster to learn about.